# Limits of integration in multivariable integrals during change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, mathematica

I want to evaluate the following integral numerically:

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}d\lambda_1\int^{\lambda_1}_{0}d\lambda_2 \lambda_1\lambda_2(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\mathrm{Exp}[-\lambda_1\lambda_2-\lambda_1^2-\lambda_2^2]$$

The limits of integration impose the constraint that $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2$. The integral is something that can be solved analytically, and the result is

$$\frac{1}{18}(9-5\sqrt{3})\sqrt{\pi} = 0.0334547$$

I can't numerically evaluate this integral directly since there's a limit of $\lambda_1$ in one of the integrals, and symbols + numerical integration don't mix. So I change variables using $x_1=\lambda_1$, $x_2=\lambda_1-\lambda_2$. The Jacobian of this transform is $-1$, and the new integral is:

$$\int^\infty_0 dx_1\int^\infty_0 dx_2 x_1x_2(x_1-x_2)\mathrm{Abs}[-1]\mathrm{Exp}[-x_1(x_1-x_2)-x_1^2-(x_1-x_2)^2]$$

My argument for using these limits of integration are that $x_1=\lambda_1$ is a trivial transform, so it has the same limits of integration. Meanwhile since $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2$, their difference is positive, but could still range from $0$ to $\infty$.

The problem is, when I numerically integrate this with Mathematica, it produces the answer $-1.739$. I don't see how this is possible. Every term in the integrand is positive, so the integral cannot evaluate to a negative number. Even more bafflingly, if I integrate $x_2$ from $0$ to $-\infty$ (as opposed to $0$ to $\infty$), Mathematica produces the correct answer of $0.0334547$!

Can anyone explain what's going on? My best guess is that the Jacobian being negative flips the orientation of the integral such that I'm supposed to integrate from $0$ to $-\infty$, but that still doesn't explain how the limits of integration can change so haphazardly. After all, integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ is in general not related to integrating from $0$ to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits for $x_2$ look wrong.   They should be from $x_1 \ to\ 0$, which need to be reversed.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate? $\lambda_2$ ranges from $0$ to $\lambda_1$. When $\lambda_2 = 0$, $x_2 = x_1$, but $x_1$ can range from 0 to infinity, so the top limit should be infinity. Similarly when $\lambda_2 = \lambda_1$, $x_2$ would be zero, which is the bottom limit. Also, if I have to introduce $x_2$ in the limit, won't it no longer be numerically integrable? After all, numerical integration doesn't work on symbols.

Comment: When $\lambda_2=0, \ x_2=x_1.$  The $x_1$ range comes into play after the $x_2$ integration.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct. Would you say the fact that Mathematica produces the right answer if the limits of the integral are flipped is a coincidence?

Comment: I suspct that an analysis of the integrals involved would show that they are equal.  It is unlikely (but possible) that it is a coincidence.